# Toshiba External HDD USB 3.0 not being recognized by Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: usb, external-hdd

My USB 3.0 1TB Toshiba External HDD works fine with my Windows desktop and my Xubuntu 16.04 LTS laptop. Both of them recognize and utilize the USB 3.0 feature of my hard drive. However my other laptop (now with Elementary OS Loki, which is based on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS) fails to recognize my external HDD when I plug it in a USB 3.0 port even though it works fine when I plug it to a USB 2.0 port.

I know that there are other threads similar to my problem but I'm quite confused because my external HDD works with my Xubuntu laptop but doesn't work with my current Elementary OS laptop (btw it also didn't work for this laptop when it was still running the same distro, but I think it worked when this was still running Fedora 24). I can't really say that my USB 3.0 port is broken because it works fine with my USB 3.0 flash drives. I'm thinking that maybe there are some packages that I need to install/remove to make it work.

I don't know if this will help but I'll include it anyway:

- Laptop: Acer Travelmate P246M-MG
- CPU   : Intel Core i7 4510u
- GPU   : Nvidia 820m
- RAM   : 8 GB
- HDD   : 1 TB, 7200 RPM
- OS    : GNU/Linux Elementary OS 0.4 Loki

I would really appreciate any help. Thank you in advance! :D

Comment: I'd considering a faulty/bad USB3 port.

Answer (score 0):

Try connecting the laptop to power, then connect the hard drive. It worked for me.

I also have a Toshiba 1 TB external hard drive with USB 3.0 connection. When I plugged it into my Asus Zenbook UX305UA with elementary OS Loki running on battery, the hard drive was not recognized, neither on the USB 3.0 nor the USB 2.0 port (although it got powered up...). Only once I connected the laptop to power and then plugged in the hard drive, it popped up in the file manager.

Also as somewhere else suggested, you might want to make sure you have the ntfs-3g package installed, if your hard drive is formatted as NTFS.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but still no luck. :(
Btw does your wallpaper get ruined after you lock/suspend/logout?

Comment: No my wallpaper does not change after lock, suspend or logout.